# Parsing custom serialized object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I am able to export a serialized text representation of an object from our proprietary CNC programming software and need to parse it to import objects in my Rails app.

**Example serialized output:**

```
Header {
    code    "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS"
    label   "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS"
    lccShortname    "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS"
    jobgroup    "20170117 - Pike Sign"
    waste   97.5516173272
    unit    INCH
    Material {
        code    "HRS"
        label   "HRS"
        labelDIN    "HRS"
        density 0.283647787542
        thickness   0.125
    }
}
Rawmaterials {
    Rawmaterial {
        id  52312
        format  120 48.25
        stock   +999
        used    +1
    }
}
Parts {
    Part {
        id  1
        code    "8581-Sign"
        label   "8581-Sign"
        need    +2
        used    +2
        priority    +1
        turnAngleIncrement  +180
        ccAllowed   +0
        filler  +0
        area    141.761356753
        positioningTime 10.369402427
        cuttingTime 346.222969467
        piercingTime    35.5976025504
        positioningWay  1949.56
        cuttingWay  9249.13
        countPiercingNormal +75
        countPiercingPuls   +4
    }
}
Plans {
    Plan {
        id  52313
        label   "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS 1"
        filename    "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS01"
        border  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
        cycleCount  +1
        waste   97.5516173272
        positioningTime 11.9357066923
        cuttingTime 345.629256802
        piercingTime    35.5976025504
        auxiliaryProcessTime    79.2405450926
        positioningWay  1954.13
        cuttingWay  9215.92
        countPiercingNormal +75
        countPiercingPuls   +4
        RawmaterialReference    52312
        PartReferences {
            PartReference {
                id  1
                layer   21
                partId  1
                insert  -128.833464567 -97.2358267717
            }
        }
    }
    Plan {
        id  52314
        label   "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS 2"
        filename    "Centric 20170117 16gaHRS02"
        border  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
        cycleCount  +1
        waste   97.5516173272
        positioningTime 11.9357066923
        cuttingTime 345.629256802
        piercingTime    35.5976025504
        auxiliaryProcessTime    79.2405450926
        positioningWay  1954.13
        cuttingWay  9215.92
        countPiercingNormal +75
        countPiercingPuls   +4
        RawmaterialReference    52312
        PartReferences {
            PartReference {
                id  1
                layer   21
                partId  1
                insert  -128.833464567 -97.2358267717
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To start with, I would like to extract the `code` attribute from the `Header` section, and the `filename` attribute for each `Plan`.

I could iterate through the file keeping note of curly braces and which section we are currently processing, but it seems as though there must be a simpler way. I could easily parse it if it were JSON or XML data, but I am at a loss as to the simplest way to parse this non-standard format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way.

A json and xml parser does exactly the same, going through the file character by character and keeping track of everything, just that someone else wrote that code for you.

I see 5 options

- you do as suggested, reading line by line and partially parsing the file. That is called an "island grammar" parser
- you use a series of regular expressions to turn the file into a valid JSON file and then parse that, the formats look similar enough that it might be possible
- you reverse engineer the format and write your own complete parser
- you get the name of the file format from the proprietary vendor and search for a gem that implements a parser. Most likely there will be none
- you get the proprietary vendor to export the data in a different format. Most likely they will charge an astronomic price or just say no

I would give the first two options a try …

Comment: I ended up writing a custom parser for the proprietary format.

Comment: Good choice, you picked the most fun option! :)